# Use of unresolved identifier 'self' in UICollectionView func

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, self

I have called the UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate and linked the outlets on the Main.Storyboard in code.  This error occurs at this line:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return self.categories.count
}
```

Also categories,

```
var categories : [Category] = []
```

Comment: where do you declare categories ?

Comment: @EICaptain in an entity

Comment: I am trying to create a parent entity

Comment: The most likely reason for that error is that you have accidentally defined that function outside of any class or struct.

Comment: @robmayoff you are right, I had an extra bracket above the numberOfItemsInSection func Thanks!